# Switching from sdk 29 to 31. I get this error

Tags: sdk

I'm trying to upgrade from sdk 29 to 31 I am getting this error:

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compileSdk() for arguments [31] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to version 31

`$` buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'